# Spring Boot Graphql: How can I pre-process an individual query/mutation before it runs the controller method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, java-annotations, spring-graphql

I want to add an annotation to my controller methods that is used to check if the user can perform an action or access a piece of data before the controller method is called.

I want to be able to check each individual query/mutation, rather than each http request which may come with multiple queries or mutations.

I assume Spring's GraphQL framework has a way of intercepting graphql queries/mutations before (and probably after) the corresponding controller method is run, but I don't know what to call it and thus haven't been able to find documentation or a tutorial on it.

Comment: You can override intercept method of WebGraphQlInterceptor class in java and view request body and filter there and decide to continue with further steps or not. What exactly is your use case. Why do you want to intercept request then I can give some more info.

Comment: Use case is blocking queries/mutations individually based on user's permissions or lack thereof. I already have a request-level filter, I don't want to implement it there because I want each query/mutation to be evaluated separately because they have different permission requirements.

Comment: Have you looked at the GraphQL Directive? I wrote one article on Directive - https://techdozo.dev/graphql-directive/ - It has an example of field-level access control using Directive, check if you can extend that concept to Query.

Comment: @Mar did you find the solution to this problem? I am having a similar scenario